Bash error trap does not catch stderr output after redirection to file
In my bash script I redirected stdout and stderr to a logs file to prevent it from being printed in the terminal.
I set my script to exit on error occurrence using set -e switch.
Now, whenever any part of the code fails (exits with a non-zero exit code) the script stops being executed (as intended), but the trap part does not print my custom error message.
Additionally, when script stops execution, it doesn't print a new line, resulting in the prompt staying in the same line as the last thing that was echoed by the bash script.
Bash script:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

###############################
#       env variables
###############################

#Environmental variables - paths to files storing installation logs and dependencies names to be installed
readonly LOGS_DIRECTORY="./logs/cherry-install/"
readonly LOGS_FILE=""$LOGS_DIRECTORY""$(date +%d-%m-%y_%H-%M-%S)".txt"
readonly ZYPPER_PACKAGES="./dependencies/zypper_packages.txt"
readonly ZYPPER_PATTERNS="./dependencies/zypper_patterns.txt"

###############################
#  non-installation functions
###############################

#Create logs directory
mkdir -p "$LOGS_DIRECTORY"

#Redirect stdout and stderr to logs file
exec 3>&1 1>>"$LOGS_FILE" 2>&1 
echo() (
   >&3 command echo "$@"
)

#Force script to exit on ERR occurence
set -e

#Error handler to call on ERR occurence and print an error message
error_handler(){
    echo -e " An error occured! See the installation logs file for specific information.\n" 
}
trap 'error_handler' ERR
trap "echo -e '\nInstallation terminated manually!'; exit" SIGINT

#Universal function to read dependenies names from a file
read_file(){
    packages=()
    while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        packages+=("$line")
    done < "$1"
}

###############################
#   installation functions
###############################

#Zypper repos refresh and package installation
install_zypper_packages(){
    read_file "$ZYPPER_PACKAGES"
    echo -n "[i] Refreshing zypper repositories: "
    zypper -n refresh
    echo 'OK'
    for line in "${packages[@]}"; do
        clean_line="${line//[^[:alnum:]-]/}"
        echo -n "[i] Installing "$clean_line": "
        zypper -n install -t package "$clean_line"
        echo 'OK'
    done
    echo ""
}

install_zypper_packages

Output when non-zero exit code is returned (script stops, but no trap message is printed).
lenovo:/scripts/Cherry-VM-Manager/environment-setup # ./cherry-install.sh
[i] Refreshing zypper repositories: OK
[i] Installing docker: OK
[i] Installing egvnjuiq: lenovo:/scripts/Cherry-VM-Manager/environment-setup #


Can you simplify this to a [mre]? Is the redefinition of echo with a function necessary for the problem?

The reason for no newline is because you used echo -n for that message.

If you just want to demonstrate what happens when the script gets an error, you can use false as the command to cause that, you don't need all the zypper stuff.

Please paste your script at shellcheck.net and try to implement the recommendations made there.

@Cyrus the only fixes that shellcheck.net suggests do not relate to the problem. It is suggested that I remove quotes around $LOGS_DIRECTORY in $LOGS_FILE variable.

@Barmar redefinition of echo is required, because with the redirection of output streams no text would be printed to the terminal.

The quotes there are definitely strange. Why do you have the doublequotes in pairs? Those don't do anything.

I’m voting to close this question because the poster didn't use http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag. You definitely should remove some quotes around $LOGS_DIRECTORY in $LOGS_FILE variable and fix the other issues shellcheck will tell you about. If you've thought through the issues and decided they aren't causing your problem, still fix then as you might be wrong, they're probably going to cause other problems, and at a minimum leaving them in the code means that everyone else reading it also has to waste their time thinking through those same issues.

Never add an option (e.g. -n or -e) to echo - if you think it needs an option then use printf instead, see why-is-printf-better-than-echo.

Do you really need to install one-by-one? You can sanitize the array and then,  zypper in "${packages[@]}"

Wouldn't it make sense to redirect the echo in your error handler to /dev/tty? Otherwise the message would end up in your log file.
